# What is a correct RESTful service response to a PUT request on successful update?

Tags: rest, header, restful-architecture, http-status-code-200, http-status-code-204

What is a correct RESTful service response to a PUT request on successful update?

There are two possible responses that seem to comply with REST architectural style:

1. Return only a header without body with the status 204.

   Header:

   ```
   content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
   status: 204 No Content
   ratelimit-limit: 5000
   ratelimit-remaining: 4816
   ratelimit-reset: 1444931833
   ```
2. Return a header with the status 200 and a body that contains the actual representation of an entity after an update.

   Header:

   ```
   content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
   status: 200 OK
   ratelimit-limit: 5000
   ratelimit-remaining: 4816
   ratelimit-reset: 1444931833
   ```

   Body:

   ```
   {
     "foo": "bar",
     "baz": "qux"
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

If your response includes returned data then its status should be 200, otherwise 204.